# Google Talk's Graphics Toolkit?

Tags: windows, user-interface, toolkit

What graphics toolkit is used for the Window's Google Talk application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't much information on this out there but it seems to be their own customized controls plus an IE component (and not Qt like Google Earth). [This forum thread](http://www.customizetalk.com/forums/viewtopic.php?t=841&postdays=0&postorder=asc&start=0) has a little bit of information.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not positive but I believe it's QT.