# What's UI framework using by Google to build Gtalk?

Tags: user-interface, google-talk

I like Gtalk's GUI very much. It's clear, simple, and pretty.
I don't know What's UI framework using by Google to build Gtalk?

Thanks for help.

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34711/google-talks-graphics-toolkit?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I can say it's [QT](http://www.qtsoftware.com/products/) (Edit: I'm wrong! See this: [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34711/google-talks-graphics-toolkit))

Edit 2:
However, you could try to achieve similar results using Qt and their [style sheets](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.5/stylesheet.html).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the [Google Web Toolkit](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/)?

Comment: Thank you, but I'm asking about the desktop version.

Comment: Oh, apologies. Haven't seen it.

Answer (score 0):

Google have a tenancy to develop their own in house solutions for things such as UI toolkits and the like. They have in the past used the QT toolkit to develop google earth. And it appears that they may be using a modified version of QT for Google Talk, although it is almost impossible to provide a comprehensive answer.